# Tesseract, Is there any way to show probability of predicted character from Tesseract 4.0?

Tags: ocr, tesseract

Is there any way to show probability of predicted character from Tesseract 4.0? Thanks.

Comment: As far as I remember you can only get per-word confidence using tesseract CLI, but if you choose c++ - you can set RIL_SYMBOL result iterator and get confidence per character.

Comment: Is there any solution for this? Tesseract is quite fragile and does not work well for fairly simple examples. The *default* should be to return an array of top k probabilities and chars for each of the char boxes.